# I'm facing an issue in my React application where I'm implementing JWT authentication

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, jwt

Question:

```
I'm implementing JWT authentication in my React application and encountering an issue with an infinite loop in the Axios interceptor responsible for refreshing the access token. Users receive both access and refresh tokens after sign-in, but when the access token expires, the interceptor gets stuck in a loop. I'm seeking help in identifying and resolving this issue.
```

After the access token expires, I'm encountering difficulties obtaining a new access token using the refresh token. Despite implementing the logic for token refresh, it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Frontendcode:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import {jwtDecode} from "jwt-decode"
function SignInSignupJWT() {

    const [formData,setFormData] = useState( { name:'',password:'' } )
    const [responseData,setresponseData] = useState()
    const [responseSignIn,setresponseSignIn] = useState();
    const [signInData,setsignInData] = useState( {nameSignIn:'',passwordSignIn:''} );

    const formFunction=(value,name)=>{

        setFormData( {...formData,[name]:value} )
        // below is the signin holding data
      }

      const signInFunction=(value,name)=>{
        setsignInData({...signInData,[name]:value} )
        // console.log(signInData);
      }

      

      const refreshTokenFunction=async()=>{
        // let response;
           
         await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/refreshToken',{ refreshToken:localStorage.getItem('refreshToken') }  )
         .then((response)=>{
          console.log(response.data);
                  return response.data;
         }).catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error);
                console.log('this is error function block while calling refresh token function');
         })
     
      }
    // why the below one is needed  because  i want to check my access token whether its expired or not for every request.
    // this function will be called whenever we make a request to server
    
      
      const axiosJWT= axios.create();//if below not wroking then use this instead
      //  the above one is the problem solver my careless i used the same axios but i didn't create new one for interceptor that's why it was gone infinitely
    let isRefreshing = false;
    axios.interceptors.request.use(
      async (config) => {
        try {
          const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
          console.log(accessToken);// i dont know excutes twice 
          console.log('this is access token in axios interceptors request');
    
          if (accessToken && !isRefreshing) {
            const tokenDecoded = await jwtDecode(accessToken);
            console.log(tokenDecoded);//it contains payload,iat,exp property
            console.log("this is token decoded in frontend axios interceptors");
    
            const currentDate = new Date();
            console.log(tokenDecoded.exp);
            console.log(currentDate.getTime());
            console.log("both are we check the condition");
            if (tokenDecoded.exp * 1000 < currentDate.getTime()) {
               
            console.log('this is inside the condition of access token');
            //upto here it's printing.
              isRefreshing = true;
              try {
                const data = await refreshTokenFunction();
                console.log(data);
                console.log('the below is the data from which we request for a new access token by calling refreshToken() ');
                config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${data.accessToken}`;
    
                console.log("your access token is now created newly..");
                console.log(data.accessToken);
    
                localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.accessToken);
              } catch (error) {
                console.log('error in refreshing token', error);
              } finally {
                isRefreshing = false;
              }
            }
          }
    
          return config;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error in axios interceptors' + error);
          throw error;
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error in Axios interceptor:', error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
    


      const signInHandler=async(event,signInData)=>{
      
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(signInData);
        let backendresponse;
        try {
            backendresponse= await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/realUserSignin',signInData)
            console.log(backendresponse);
            console.log('the above is the backend response in sign in ');
            // setresponseSignIn(backendresponse.data.message)
            localStorage.setItem("id",backendresponse.data.id);
            localStorage.setItem("accessToken",backendresponse.data.accessToken);
            localStorage.setItem("refreshToken",backendresponse.data.refreshToken);
//front end ok working
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          console.log('this is error handling and error block in sigin in handler function');
          setresponseSignIn(error.response.data.message)
        }
  }

  const submitHandler=async (event,formData)=>{
       event.preventDefault();
       console.log(formData);
       let backendresponse='';
     try {
        backendresponse= await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/realUserSignup', formData)
       // store it in usestate backendresponse.data
         console.log(backendresponse);
         console.log('the above is backend response posting user');
           setresponseData(backendresponse.data.message)
           console.log(responseData);
     }
     catch (error) {
       setresponseData(error.response.data.message)
       console.log('there is an error in posting the user',error);
     }
       
       
  }
// we can also continue to send the body of data also in request so dont' worry.
  const button1=async()=>{
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    const headers={
      
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    }
          const response= await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/dummyapi1',headers);
          console.log(response.data);
          console.log('this is the message from dummy api 1 api');

  }

  const button2= async()=>{
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    const headers={
      
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    }
    const response= await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/dummyapi2',headers);
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log('this is the message from dummy api 2 api');

}

  
     return (
        <>
            <h1>sign in signup using JWT concept:</h1>
            <br />
{/*  front end work create sign up and sign in area and if we authenticate is valid in sign in create some new route for backend try to access it also */}
     <div>

              <div>

                <form onSubmit={ (event)=>{ submitHandler(event,formData) } }>
                        <div>
                        <h3>sign up</h3>
                            <div> 
                                <label>name</label>
                                <input name="name" onChange={ (event)=> formFunction(event.target.value,event.target.name)   } type="text"></input>
                            </div>
                            

                            {/* ------------ */}
                                <div> 
                                <label>password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" onChange={ (event)=>{ formFunction(event.target.value,event.target.name) } } ></input>

                                 </div>

                            <button type="submit">sign up !</button>

                            {/* <p>result :{responseData}</p> */}
                       </div>
                </form>
              </div>

              <div>
                {/* for signin */}
                <h5>sign in</h5>

                <form onSubmit={ (event)=>{ signInHandler(event,signInData) } }>
                        <div>
                            <div> 
                                <label>username</label>
                                <input name="nameSignIn" onChange={(event)=>{ signInFunction(event.target.value,event.target.name) } } type="text"></input>
                            </div>
                            

                            
                                <div> 
                                <label>password</label>
                                <input type={'password'} name="passwordSignIn" onChange={(event)=>{ signInFunction(event.target.value,event.target.name) } } ></input>

                            </div>

                            <button type="submit">sign in !</button>

                            {/* <p>result :
                            {responseSignIn}
                            </p> */}
                            </div>
                  </form> 
                
                <button onClick={()=> button1()}>button 1</button>
                <button onClick={()=> button2()}>button 2</button>
              </div>
   </div>   
        </>
    )
}

export default SignInSignupJWT
```

BackendCode:

```
const express = require('express');
const app=express();
const mysql= require('mysql')

   const JWTFunction= require("./JWTFunction.js")
const jwt=require('jsonwebtoken')// this is is to ensure our authentication and authorization by token 
const jwtDecode= require('jwt-decode');
// const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// jwt.sign this is used to create jwt token and we will add this with response which is given by server.. 
//in client side it placed in header of request 

jwt.sign({id:1,userName:'gulzar ahamed'},"mysecretkey")
app.use(express.json());

  // this is to validate my user token client token with exist token 

  // jwt.verify(userdata,"mysecretkey")
// u can also use express.json () in use funciton
// app.use(express.json());  to convert all the data to json format automatically

app.use(express.urlencoded( { extended: true} ));

const cors = require('cors'); // Import cors module
const { response } = require('express');

   const pool=mysql.createPool(
        {
          connectionLimit:2,
          user:'root',
          password:'Gulzar_123',
          host:'localhost', 
          database:"backendfrontend"       
        }
    )


    const db=mysql.createPool(
      {
        connectionLimit:6,
        user:'root',
        password:'Gulzar_123',
        host:'localhost', 
        database:"authenticationjwt"       
      }
  )

  const refreshDB=mysql.createPool(
    {
      connectionLimit:2,
      user:'root',
      password:'Gulzar_123',
      host:'localhost', 
      database:"authenticationjwt"        
    }
)
const errorHandler=(error,req,res,next)=>{
// this is error handler middleware
  res.status(error.statusCode).json( {message:`${error.statusCode} this is the error message`} )
  //  next();

};

// app.use(errorHandler); thisis for global error handling but not for now

let count=1;
const middlewarefunforpost = (req, res, next) => {
 
  // Check if the request method is POST
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    console.log('this is middleware function for POST request');
    // Your logic for handling POST requests goes here i dont know why 2 times function executes
       console.log(count++); 
    // ...
  }
  next(); // Continue processing the request
};
  
// app.use(middlewarefunforpost);// if u want to execute only on time then ignore thi line and declare function name directly in routes.

//Use cors middleware this may help to cross-domain requests
app.use(cors());

app.get('/backendapitesting', (req, res) => {
    res.json( 
            {
                "clientName":["Gulzar","ahamed","sahira","vivek",'GOKUL','anand']
            }
        )
});

app.get("/gulzar", (req, res) => {

    res.send('hello gulzar ahamed')
});
// chatGPT exercise
let data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Item 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Item 2' },
];
console.log(data);
console.log('below is data of backend');
// Get all items
app.get('/items', (req, res) => {
  res.json(data);
});
// Get a specific item by ID
app.get('/items/:id', (req, res) => {
  const itemId = parseInt(req.params.id);
  const item = data.find(item => item.id === itemId);

  if (item) {
    res.json(item);
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({ message: 'Item not found' });
  }
});
// Create a new item
app.post('/items',middlewarefunforpost, (req, res) => {
  const newItem = req.body;
  console.log(newItem);
  newItem.id = data.length + 1;// now newly inserted item got id property
  data.push(newItem);
  res.status(201).json(newItem);
});

// Update an existing item by ID
app.put('/items/:id', (req, res) => {
  const itemId = parseInt(req.params.id);
  const updatedItem = req.body;

  data = data.map(item => (item.id === itemId ? updatedItem : item));

  res.json(updatedItem);
});

// Delete an item by ID
app.delete('/items/:id', (req, res) => {
  const itemId = parseInt(req.params.id);
  data = data.filter(item => item.id !== itemId);
  res.json({ message: 'Item deleted successfully' });
});

// this is a differnet exercise to validate data help of middleware

const userDatabase=[
      {name:'gulzar',password:'abc'},
      {name:'ahamed',password:'def'},
      {name:'gulzar ahamed',password:'abcdef'}
]
     

const validatorMiddleware=async(req,res,next)=>{

  const {name,password} = req.body;

  const user= userDatabase.find(user => user.name === name && user.password === password);

     if (!user) {// check if user exists in database or not if it returns object then 
       // then user will have data if not it will be undefined

      //  res.status(404).json( { message: 'User not found' } );
      //  above is ok but it's better to handle errors in error handling which is common approach
            const error= new Error("User not found");
            error.statusCode=404;
           
            console.log(error.message);
            console.log(error.stack);
            return next(error);
     }
        res.status(200).json( {message: `welome ${name} `} );
    //  next();
}

app.post('/validate',validatorMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  // no need send response already written in middleware
})

//a) database fetching starts here 

     app.get('/backendData',(req,res)=>{
      const dbQuery='SELECT * FROM userinfo'
      pool.query(dbQuery,(error, results,fields) => {
            if (error) {
              console.log(`this is error in MYSQL query: ${error}`);
  
              return
            }
            return  res.status(200).json(results)
      })
     })


const postUserMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, password } = req.body;

  // this is function; we have to change our logic because it first approaches for error.
  const sqlInsertQuery = 'INSERT INTO realuserinfo (name, password) VALUES (?, ?)';

  pool.query(sqlInsertQuery, [name, password], (error, result, fields) => {
    try {
      if (error) {
        // console.error('Error inserting user data:', error);
        // const mysqlError = new Error('Internal Server Error');
        // mysqlError.statusCode = 500;
        // return next(mysqlError);
        console.log('Unexpected error object from MySQL');
      const conflictError = new Error('Conflict: User already exists, operation failed');
      conflictError.status = 'conflict user exist';
      conflictError.statusCode = 409;
console.log(conflictError);
return res.status(conflictError.statusCode).json( { message: conflictError.message } )
      // return next(conflictError);
      }
      // req.body = result;
      next();
    }
     catch (_error) {
      console.error(_error);
      console.log('Unexpected error object from MySQL');
      // const conflictError = new Error('Conflict: User already exists, operation failed');
      // conflictError.status = 'conflict user exist';
      // conflictError.statusCode = 409;
      // return next(conflictError);
    }
  });
};

     app.post('/postingUser', postUserMiddleware ,(req,res)=>{

      console.log(req.body);
       console.log(' this is reuqest body in postinguser route')

      res.status(200).json( {message: 'success: user added to database'} )
     
            }
         )
    //  })
           
    app.post('/signInUser',(req,res)=>{
        //  if this  function returns errro then it's because of if no user eixist in db then error
        // if no error means user is exist so send response like welcome USERNAME
            const {nameSignIn,passwordSignIn}= req.body;
console.log(req.body);
console.log('above is the req.body value from backend');

              try {
                  const sqlSelectQuery='SELECT name,password from realuserinfo WHERE name=? AND password=?';
               
                        pool.query(sqlSelectQuery,[nameSignIn,passwordSignIn],(error,result,fields)=>{

                             
                          // if(result.length)
                        console.log(result);
                        console.log('above is the result from dabbase');

                              if(result.length > 0){
                                 res.status(200).json( { message:`hi ${result[0].name} ` })
                              }else{
                                res.status(401).json(  { message:"user not exist so unautheriased access" } )
                              }
                        })
                  }
               catch (error) {
                    if(error){
                       res.status(500).json( {message:"internal server error .."} )
                      }
              }
            
    })    



// -----------------------------------here our JWT logic and concepts starts.----------------------------------------------------------------------------


   app.post('/realUserSignup',(req,res)=>{

          const{name,password}=  req.body;
          // if username,password is not available send this error message:

          if( !name || !password ){
            res.status(401).json( {message:"username or password not available"})
          }

          db.query('INSERT INTO realuserauthentication (name,password) VALUES (?, ?)',[name,password],(error,result)=>{
                  
                  if(error){
                       res.status(409).json( {message:"internal server error user already exist .."} )
                  }
                  else{
                    res.status(201).json({message:"user created successfully"})
                  }

             }
          )

    }
 )
   
 app.post('/realUserSignin',async(req,res)=>{  // now this is working in all cases:
        // this is working when i comment out hte axios.
      const{nameSignIn,passwordSignIn}= req.body;
      if( !nameSignIn || !passwordSignIn ){
       return  res.status(401).json( {message:"username or password not available"})
      }
      // check if user already exist or not if not throw error.

   try {
        db.query("SELECT * FROM  realuserauthentication WHERE name=? AND password=?",[nameSignIn,passwordSignIn],(error,result)=>{
          if (error) {
          return  res.status(500).json( {message:'internal server error user not exist '} )
          }
       
          const id=result[0].id;
       const  accessToken= JWTFunction.generateAccessToken(id);
       const refreshToken= JWTFunction.generateRefreshToken(id);
        
          console.log(result);// returns array
          console.log("this is result from DB after we are checking name and password ");
          // create access token and refresh token and send as response to user it will store in local storage
        // }
        // store the refresh token in separeate table.
        // then send both tokens to user.
        console.log(id);
        console.log('this is id from DB');
        console.log(refreshToken);// can log it
        console.log('this is refresh token after sign in');
          // if (!refreshToken) {
          // return  res.status(401).json( {message:"refresh token not available"} );
          // }
//below is not working.. some problem now working
          
            console.log(result.length > 0);// this is working dummy

            // storing refresh token in DB
            refreshDB.query('SELECT * FROM refreshtokentable where  id=?',[id],(error,result)=>{ // i faced error because i didn't use logic properly..

                    if(error){
                        res.status(401).json({message:"refresh token not available"})
                    }
                      if(result.length > 0)
                       {
                        
                              refreshDB.query('UPDATE refreshtokentable SET refreshtoken=? WHERE id=?',[refreshToken,id],(error,result)=>{
                              
                                      if (error) {
                                        res.status(403).json( {message:"error while updating the refresh token in database"})
                                      }
                                      
                                      else{
                                        console.log(result);
                                        console.log('log message of updating the refresh token in database');
                                      }
                                }
                            )
        
                        }

                       else
                        {
                            refreshDB.query('INSERT INTO refreshtokentable (id, refreshtoken) VALUES (?,?)',[id,refreshToken],(error,result)=>{

                              if (error) {
                                return   res.status(401).json( {message:"server error while inserting refresh token"} );
                              }
          
                            console.log(result);
                            console.log('refresh token inserted successfully');
                          })
                        }

                  }
             )

          res.json( {id,accessToken,refreshToken} );// no need of key if the key and value names are same.
      })
    }
      catch (error) {
        console.log(" there is an error in this code "+ error);
      }
     
 }
)
const Authorization=(req,res,next)=>{
  // here get the access token from user.
  let accessToken ;

      if (!accessToken) {
       return  res.status(401).json({message:'access token missing please authenticate'})
      }

     const user= jwt.verify(accessToken,JWTFunction.accessTokenSecretKey)
     if (!user) {
         return res.status(403).json({message:'access Denited'})
     }     
      req.user = user;

      next();
}
// this is about refrsh token we will issue once access is expired
app.post('/refreshToken',async(req,res)=>{
  const { refreshToken } = req.body;

  if(!refreshToken){
    return res.status(401).json( {message:"refresh token is required"})
  }

  console.log(refreshToken);
  console.log('refresh token is in /refreshToken')
  //   i need to check the condition when only i need to approach or calling acces token and return to user.
  // the condition is  i need to  check the frontend refresh token same or not if matches then generate new access token
try {
      const userDecoded = jwt.verify(refreshToken,JWTFunction.refreshTokenSecretKey)
     
      console.log(userDecoded);// this will give iat and exp property also that's why we use  
    console.log('this is userDecoded value in refresh tokens and its using verfiy ()');

    const isRefreshTokenValid = async(id,refreshToken,callback)=>{//i think function definition 
     
      refreshDB.query("SELECT * FROM refreshTokentable WHERE id=? AND refreshtoken=?",[id,refreshToken],(error,result)=>{
       // get the refresh token from frontend. may be from local storage.
           if (error) {
               callback(false)
             res.status(404).json( {message:'refresh token invalid sorry...'} )
           }   
           else{
            console.log('else block is refresh token function');
           }
       }
   )

 }
     await isRefreshTokenValid(userDecoded.id,refreshToken,(isValid)=>{
        //i think this is  function calling..
            if(!isValid) {
              return res.status(403).json( {message:'invalid refresh token in isRefreshTokenValid function calling'} )
            }
// now this is not working function 
            const newAcessToken=   JWTFunction.generateAccessToken(userDecoded.id);//Check point
            console.log(newAcessToken);
            console.log('this is the new access token');
            res.status(201).json( {accessToken:newAcessToken} ) 
        } 
     )

 }
     catch (error) {
      return res.status(403).json( {message:'invalid refresh token in catch block'} )
    }

  // below is function calling need to understand first
  }
)

app.get('/dummyapi1',Authorization,(req,res)=>{
      res.send("welcome to dummy api 1")
    }
)

app.get('/dummyapi2',Authorization,(req,res)=>{
  res.send("welcome to dummy api 2")
}
)

app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log('server running on port 5000');
})
const  JWT=require("jsonwebtoken")
const accessTokenSecretKey="accesstokensecretkey"
const  refreshTokenSecretKey="refreshtokensecretkey" 
const generateAccessToken = (userId)=>{

  return JWT.sign( {id:userId},accessTokenSecretKey,{expiresIn:"20s"} )
}

const generateRefreshToken = (userId)=>{

  return JWT.sign( {id:userId},refreshTokenSecretKey,{expiresIn:"15d"} )
  }


  
  module.exports.generateAccessToken = generateAccessToken;
  module.exports.generateRefreshToken = generateRefreshToken;
  module.exports.accessTokenSecretKey = accessTokenSecretKey;
  module.exports.refreshTokenSecretKey = refreshTokenSecretKey;
```

explanation: the problem is when i am checking whether  the  access token  expired  or not in each request through axios.interceptors inside condition is met it call the refreshToken() that has responsbility to provide new access token i consloe.log () the axios.interceptors code but it doesn't call refreshtoken so that i can't get the new access token